# Empty response in gsm run algorithm command

Tags: gsm, apdu, sim-card

I am trying to use `run gsm algorithm` command using RUIM tool. The response is `97 0C`, but there is no data on Dataout.

The command i am using is.

```
A088 0000 10 AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

where `AA..` is the random number (16 bytes).

Before running this command, I have selected `DFgsm` file. Successful verification of CHV1 is also done, but still no data on dataout.

Kindly tell me what can be the cause or how to debug it. I am new to this domain so please ignore the mistakes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only have some experience on GSM USIMs and to my knowledge `SW1=97` usually refers to a key/pin issue. however since I see `SW2=0C` it may be that it is correct for RUIM or CDMA SIMs.

So here is a trace of a successful GSM Run GSM Algo:

```
> A0 88 00 00 10 AA AA AA AA AA AA AA AA AA AA AA AA AA AA AA AA
<  [] 9F 0C
> A0 C0 00 00 0C
< 30 E8 30 F8 E6 6A B2 9D 5D 5D 5F F9 90 00
```

So I suggest you run the "GET_RESPONSE" APDU i.e. `A0 C0 00 00` + `SW2`

Regards,

Comment: do you know how to verify adm?

Comment: ADM verification is vendor specific. However it is normally a spin on verify chv command with specific P2 parameter.

Comment: can you please tell me what is the p2 parameter?

Comment: As per the comment above each vendor is different. Please ask the cars vendor.

Comment: what if i have a blank sim?